# Strain potential energy and the spring extension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, spring

There is a spring with springs constant $k =200 N/m$. The spring is held vertically and a mass of 2 kg is attached to it. We will assume that $g=10 m/s^2$. The extension of the spring is to be found. The same can be found in two different ways.

1. kx = mg --> x = 2*10/200 = 0.1 m
2. The second method is using energy. The 2kg mass would lose GPE (loss of height = x), which would go into the spring as its strain potential energy.
   mgx = 0.5*k*x^2 --> x = 0.2m

Why are the two answers are different? I know that the first answer is correct, but why is the second method not correct? In fact, no matter what numbers I take, the second answer is always twice the first one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you hang 2kg mass  at a spring it moves beyond the equilibrium point and starts to oscillate around the 0,1m.

Comment: Thanks. that is right, but i am talking about the equilibrium position. We gently lower the mass so that there are no oscillations. In this position, the mass has lost height by x and the resulting loss of GPE got transferred to springs.

Comment: If we "gently" lower the mass, we extend a force to it,  energy is not conserved.

Comment: When Ithink about this it makes sense now. Thanks